# BootStrap 4.1 - Justify Tab with Drop Down in a Modal Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working with Bootstrap 4.1 and I'm having a problem to getting the right justify to work. Basically I have a Navigation Bar that launches a Modal Dialog with Tabs. The Tab on the far right side is a drop down menu. The drop down menu on the far right is the one I want to right justify.  Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Added `ml-auto` to the `<li class='nav-item active dropdown'>` tag in the portion of the code commented with: "Modal - Drop Down"
2. Added `mr-auto` to the `<ul class="nav nav-tabs mr-auto" role="tablist">`  tag in the portion of the code commented with: "Modal - Drop Down"
3. Added `justify-content-end` to the `<li class="nav-item active dropdown justify-content-end">`  tag in the portion of the code commented with: "Modal - Drop Down"
4. Added `ml-auto` to the `<li class="nav-item active dropdown justify-content-end ml-auto">`  tag in the portion of the code commented with: "Modal - Drop Down"
5. Flex classes - `<div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse bd-highlight">, <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">, <div class="d-flex align-items-end">, <div class="align-self-end">`

But nothing is working.

Has anyone else done this with Bootstrap 4.1?

My code is available on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tsmolskow/jm19hu3t/66/

My HTML code is below:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<!-- Navigation Bar -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SharePointGypsy.com</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" aria-label="Toggle navigation" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
        </button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="nav-item active"> 
               <a class="nav-link" id="Departments" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyNNSModal">Departments</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item active"> 
               <a class="nav-link" id="Resources" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyNNSModal">Resources</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item active"> 
               <a class="nav-link" id="Procedures" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyNNSModal">Procedures</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item active"> 
               <a class="nav-link" id="News" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyNNSModal">News</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Modal -->

      <div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="MyNNSModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
         <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <div class="tabbable">

                     <!-- Nav Tabs, Modal Nav Bar -->

                           <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                              <li class="nav-item active">
                                 <a class="nav-link active" href="#aDepartments" data-toggle="tab">Departments</a></li>
                              <li class="nav-item active">
                                 <a class="nav-link" href="#aResources" data-toggle="tab">Resources</a></li>
                              <li class="nav-item active">
                                 <a class="nav-link" href="#aProcedures" data-toggle="tab">Procedures</a></li>
                              <li class="nav-item active">
                                 <a class="nav-link" href="#aNews" data-toggle="tab">News</a></li>                            
                                                      
                          </ul> 

                  </div>
                    <div class="d-flex align-self-end">
                            
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbardrop">
                                <img src="Images/KoKoPelli.jpg" class="profile-picture"/>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Newsfeed</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">One Drive</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sites</a></li> 
                            </ul>

                   </div>

                  <!-- Close Button -->

                     <div>
                        <button class="close" aria-label="Close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true"><img class="close-button" src="/sites/dscott/tmfds/SiteAssets/Images/CloseButton.png" alt=""/> </span> </button> </div>
               </div>

               <!-- Panes -->

                  <div class="modal-body">
                     <div class="tab-content">

                        <!-- Tab Panes -->

                           <div class="tab-pane active" id="aDepartments">
                              <p> 
                                 <b>Departments:</b> 
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit iusto nulla aperiam blanditiis ad consequatur in dolores culpa, dignissimos, eius non possimus fugiat. Esse ratione fuga, enim, ab officiis totam.</p>
                           </div>
                           <div class="tab-pane" id="aResources">
                              <p> 
                                 <b>Resources:</b> 
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit iusto nulla aperiam blanditiis ad consequatur in dolores culpa, dignissimos, eius non possimus fugiat. Esse ratione fuga, enim, ab officiis totam.</p>
                           </div>
                           <div class="tab-pane" id="aProcedures">
                              <p> 
                                 <b>Procedures:</b> 
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit iusto nulla aperiam blanditiis ad consequatur in dolores culpa, dignissimos, eius non possimus fugiat. Esse ratione fuga, enim, ab officiis totam.</p>
                           </div>
                           <div class="tab-pane" id="aNews">
                              <p> 
                                 <b>News:</b> 
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit iusto nulla aperiam blanditiis ad consequatur in dolores culpa, dignissimos, eius non possimus fugiat. Esse ratione fuga, enim, ab officiis totam.</p>
                           </div> 
                     </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Footer -->

              <div class="modal-footer">​​​​</div>

            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Are you fine with the alignment of the 'More' button?

Comment: If you mean that it's higher than the other tab titles, I can deal with that, I really just want the rightmost tab to be right justified.

Comment: The JSFiddle isn't working....

Comment: I corrected the JSFiddle - please recheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try? CSS:

```
.tabbable {
    width: 100%;
}

.tabbable > ul.nav.nav-tabs {
    display: table;
}

.tabbable > ul.nav.nav-tabs > li {
    width: auto;
    display: table-cell;
}

.tabbable > ul.nav.nav-tabs > li:last-child {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.tabbable > ul.nav.nav-tabs > li:last-child ul.dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I updated the code on JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tsmolskow/jm19hu3t/66/ - but the difference is still shy of having the last item on the far right - do you think that's because of the width of the drop down menu?

Comment: OK, I added just a little bit to your code, (see below), and now it works as I need it to - Thanks!

.nav-tabs > li > a {
    text-align: left;
}  

Updated code on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tsmolskow/jm19hu3t/80/

Comment: @TomMolskow Cool. It was working with your first code, but you updated it, then I did not know what to say, but I am happy that it worked for you ^^